# Gui Tool for Adaptive Server Anywhere v7.0 (sql anywhere?)

Tags: sql, sybase-asa

I have a database I need to work with which is Adaptive Server Anywhere version 7.0. I would like to run some queries and such into this database using a GUI tool. I have access to the .db file so I need to know how I can work with this.

What tools are available. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Sybase also supplies a JDBC driver, you might want to give the Java/JDBC based tools a try:

- [Squirrel](http://www.squirrelsql.org/)
- [DbVisualizer](http://www.dbvis.com/)
- [SQL Workbench/J](http://www.sql-workbench.net)

Answer (score 0):

You can give a try to ER/Studio

http://www.embarcadero.com/products/er-studio